# Skip Div In Wordpress Excerpt

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a div author box at the beginning of some of my articles and I can't figure out how to get Wordpress to filter out or skip that div when displaying excerpts on my homepage. Here's an example page: https://sciencetrends.com/increases-in-minimum-wages-lead-to-decreases-in-smoking/

I'd like to automatically filter out `<div class="article-box"> </div>` from the excerpt on the posts where it exists. Any thoughts on how to do this?

I've tried everything I can think of and searched throughout stack overflow and still can't figure it out. Anyone else that can help?

Comment: You don't want it at all?

Comment: Yea, I'd like to skip that div entirely and start the excerpt after the article-box div when it is present.

Comment: Have you tried `echo get_the_excerpt();`?

Comment: @WPZA I'm not experienced with php but I think that would just get the excerpt but it would also include the article-box div?

Comment: @Tnace Don't worry. You could perhaps try it but I think the official WP docs may mention it stips some stuff out (such as HMTL tags).